Why isn't semigroup theory applied more often to ring theory? And vice versa?
Please correct me if I am mistaken, but it seems to be the case that semigroup theory is considered much closer to group theory and that semigroup theory has developed a lot from borrowing ideas from group theory. However, the same does not seem to be true with rings.
But it certainly seems like it should be? After all, a ring is just an additive abelian group that is a multiplicate semigroup at the same time and has distributivity of $\cdot$ over $+$. Moreover, the importance of the distinction between semigroup/monoid seems to be analogous to that of ring/ring with unity (sorry if I am being vague).
From what I've taken of ring theory, an overarching theme is the divisibility of a ring. How much can I break an element up into smaller pieces or irreducibles? This is also a central question in semigroup theory, with Green's relations being perhaps the most fundamental tool for studying semigroups. In this regard, semigroup theory seems to be closer to ring theory in spirit than it is to group theory.
I know that the study of semigroups is somewhat younger, so maybe the important questions in ring theory that semigroup theory could have had an impact on were just answered before semigroups came onto the scene. What really is the hold up?

I think this question is very much opinion-based. Do you have in mind some specific results in semigroup theory that might cast new light on ring theory? (I say new light, because spare generality for its own sake  isn't necessarily helpful.)

An example of applying the analogues of Greens reltions to rings can be seen in my paper with Mazorchuk, https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06975 though this does have a lot of additional restrictions on the rings it can be applied to (and even more restrictions if it is to yield interesting results)
